# Cant validate if a user is in database or not in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm new to jsp and have some problems to validate if a user is already in the databse or not. Here's my code:

```
package bean;
import java.sql.*;
public class LoginDao {

    public static boolean validate(LoginBean bean){
        boolean status=false;
        try (Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon()) {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM test.UserInfo WHERE email = ? and password = ?";

            PreparedStatement statementSQL = con.prepareStatement(query);
            statementSQL.setString(1,  bean.getEmail());
            statementSQL.setString(2,  bean.getPassword());
            ResultSet resultSet = statementSQL.executeQuery();

            status = resultSet.next();
        } catch(Exception e){}
        return status;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that status never equals true. But the following method works just fine (I tried this one in another java class in the main method):

```
public static void getSpecificUser(String email, String password) throws SQLException {
        try (Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon()) {
            boolean status = false;
            String query = "SELECT * FROM test.UserInfo WHERE email = ? and password = ?";

            PreparedStatement statementSQL = con.prepareStatement(query);
            statementSQL.setString(1,  email);
            statementSQL.setString(2,  password);
            ResultSet resultSet = statementSQL.executeQuery();
            status = resultSet.next();
            System.out.println(status);
        }
}
```

Additional files: 
LoginBean.java

```
package bean;

public class LoginBean {
    private String email, password;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String pass) {
        this.password = pass;
    }
}
```

loginprocess.jsp (Here I always get the result false as a result for LoginDAO.validate())

```
<%@page import="bean.LoginDao"%>  
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="bean.LoginBean"/>  

<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/> 

<jsp:include page="index.jsp"></jsp:include>
 <hr/> 

<% 
    out.println(obj.getEmail());
    out.println(obj.getPassword());
    out.println(LoginDao.validate(obj));
%>
```

And the login.jsp

```
<%@ include file="index.jsp" %> 
<hr/>  

<h3>Login Form</h3>    
<br/>  
<form action="loginprocess.jsp" method="post">  
    Email:<input type="text" name="email"/><br/><br/>  
    Password:<input type="password" name="password"/><br/><br/>  
    <input type="submit" value="login"/>  
</form>
```

I hope somebody can help me because I simply cant find my mistake.

Edit: Just found out that Connection con equals null in the class LoginDao but in the getSpecificUser() Method it works just fine. I havent posted my ConnectionProvider Class so here it is:

```
package bean;
import java.sql.*;
import static bean.Provider.*;

public class ConnectionProvider {
    static Connection con=null;
    static{
        try{
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
            }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    public static Connection getCon(){
        return con;
    }
}
```

I cant understand why the Connection works in the method but not in my LoginDao Class

Comment: `} catch(Exception e){}` is not good idea, probably there is some exception and you don't see it.

Comment: The only reason why one would work and the other wouldn't is because the params are not the same, otherwise the executed query will certainly be the same.

Debug your code: check your params again, and print the exceptions that might happen.

Comment: The exception is a NullPointerException because Connection con == null in the LoginDAO class. I still have no idea why this only occurs in the LoginDAO and not in the getSpecificUser method

Comment: I can only repeat my previous comment, `catch(Exception e){}` is not good idea. Maybe `ConnectionProvider` class is loaded second time and `getConnection` throws exception.